# There is no member or method named _M_impl, how to use pvector to print STL vector of C++ compiled with clang++ and libc++,

Tags: c++, gdb

The `test.cc` is very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vector<int32_t> vec{1,2,3};

  return 0;
}
```

clang++ test.cc -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g

```
guo@dllab$ gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) l
1   #include <iostream>
2   #include <vector>
3   
4   using namespace std;
5   
6   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
7   {
8     vector<int32_t> vec{1,2,3};
9   
10    return 0;
(gdb) b 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400ca5: file test.cc, line 9.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/guo/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd718) at test.cc:10
10    return 0;
(gdb) p vec
$1 = {
  <std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >> = {
    <std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>> = {<No data fields>}, 
    members of std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >: 
    __begin_ = 0x603010, 
    __end_ = 0x60301c, 
    __end_cap_ = {
      <std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<int*, 0, false>> = {
        __value_ = 0x60301c
      }, 
      <std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::allocator<int>, 1, true>> = {
        <std::__1::allocator<int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}
  }, <No data fields>}
(gdb) pvector vec
There is no member or method named _M_impl.
```

I have installed stl-views-1.0.3.gdb via `cat stl-views-1.0.3.gdb > ~/.gdbinit`.
So `pvector` is supposed to be used.

Comment: Can you use gcc instead of clang?

Comment: Probably try these Pretty Printers for libc++: https://github.com/koutheir/libcxx-pretty-printers.

Comment: @ks1322, g++ works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stl-views is an obsolete way of inspecting C++ containers in gdb. Instead, for libstdc++ there are [python pretty printers](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py;hb=HEAD) which are part of gcc. In many Linux distributions they work out of the box. For libc++ there are no official pretty printers but there is a [3rd Party implementation](https://github.com/koutheir/libcxx-pretty-printers) which is recommended in [libc++ documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#gdb-pretty-printers-for-libc):

> GDB does not support pretty-printing of libc++ symbols by default.
>   Unfortunately libc++ does not provide pretty-printers itself. However
>   there are 3rd party implementations available and although they are
>   not officially supported by libc++ they may be useful to users.
>
> Known 3rd Party Implementations Include:
>
> ```
> Koutheir’s libc++ pretty-printers.
> ```

Comment: I installed Koutheir's libc++ pretty-printers, there is an error. But use g++
 to compile, gdb works well . the error is : (gdb) p vec
$1 = Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member or method named __first_.:.

Answer (score 0):

In your launch.json add:

```
"setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
```

More about the launch.json you can see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).